# ArrayCollection getItemAt

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, itemrenderer, arraycollection

I created an Item Renderer for the Flex Spark List Component.
The problem is that this code will not work:

```
    <s:Label left="10" right="10" top="10" bottom="10" fontSize="13" text="{data.getItemAt(1).toString()}"
         textAlign="left" verticalAlign="middle"/>
```

While this code will:

```
    <s:Label left="10" right="10" top="10" bottom="10" fontSize="13" text="{data[1].toString}"
         textAlign="left" verticalAlign="middle"/>
```

I can't use the later code because of binding issues.
Does anyone have any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: please show all the code within your item renderer and please show what is the data you're receiving.  Seems to me that there's a silent error here because the data being sent over is an Array not an ArrayCollection, hence the getItemAt function doesn't work and doesn't bind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @J_A_X' comment stated, these are two completely different things.

```
{data.getItemAt(1)...
```

Refers to an ArrayCollection, or possibly some other collection.

```
{data[1]...
```

Refers to an Array.

Attempting to treat an array as an array collection will not get you very far. I would recommend ensuring that the each item in your list is actually an ArrayCollection. Alternatively, I would more strongly support replacing them with value objects, and binding to a 'title','text', or whatever property more correctly defines the text you wish to display.

```
{data.title}
```

Comment: Yes I'm probably making a mistake. `data` is an ArrayCollection that contains Arrays. Any idea how I could convert the nested Arrays into ArrayCollections?

Comment: Where is the arraycollection of arrays coming from?